# android Retrofit POST not working - Android Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

this is my json i need to post all these

```
{
      "name": "name",
      "type": "cash",
      "PaymentStatus": true
      "CartItems": [
        {
          "ProductId": 1,
          "ProductName": "sample string 2",
          "Quantity": 3,
          "UnitPrice": 4.1,
          "Price": 5.1
        },{
          "ProductId": 1,
          "ProductName": "sample string 2",
          "Quantity": 3,
          "UnitPrice": 4.1,
          "Price": 5.1
        }
      ]
       }
```

This is my Retrofit  interface ApiService

```
@Multipart
    @POST("Addtocart")
    Call<AddtoCartRes> createOrder(@Body Order order,
                                   @HeaderMap HashMap<String,String> headerMap,
                                   @Path("name") String ShopUserName,
                                   @Path("type") String ShopName,
                                   @Path("PaymentStatus") String SalesLogin
                                  );
```

and this is my Order class
 @SerializedName("CartItems")
        List orderDetailList;

```
    public List<Cart> getOrderDetailList() {
        return orderDetailList;
    }

    public void setOrderDetailList(List<Cart> orderDetailList) {
        this.orderDetailList = orderDetailList;
    }
```

Comment: What version of retrofit are you using? Also, `@Multipart` annotation is not required for something this simple. It is used for file upload typically. There are other things needed in the API contract as well to make it work.

Comment: yeah.. i'm using retrofit2 2.4.0 @kandroidj

Comment: there is a newer version 2.5.0 available. Although that is not your issue. The endpoint you are passing data to, does it exist on your server and does it accept application/json ? also, your json is invalid. you can find the error by pasting it into https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: URL "Addtocart" does not contain "{name}". (parameter #1) i'm getting this error

Comment: This is because you have specified the @Path annotation, your url based on the above API should look like this `@POST("Addtocart/{name}/{type}/{PaymentStatus}")` which is probably wrong. maybe instead change @Path to @Query and give it another try. I really think you should checkout this tutorial -> https://futurestud.io/tutorials/tag/retrofit You need to get the basics down before doing post stuff. but this tutorial should get you started with retrofit

Comment: again this....ProductsList declares multiple JSON fields named ProductName

Answer (score 0):

Your Request Model class should be like this

```
public class CartItem {

    private int ProductId;
    private String ProductName;
    private int Quantity;
    private int UnitPrice;
    private int Price;

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        ProductId = productId;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        ProductName = productName;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(int unitPrice) {
        UnitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

This is the request model class

```
public class MyRequestModel {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private int PaymentStatus;
    private List<CartItem >  CartItems;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setPaymentStatus(int paymentStatus) {
        PaymentStatus = paymentStatus;
    }

    public void setCartItems(List<CartItem> cartItems) {
        CartItems = cartItems;
    }
}
```

your Api look like this

```
@POST("Addtocart")
Call<AddtoCartRes> createOrder(@HeaderMap HashMap<String,String> headerMap,
                                   @Body MyRequestModel order);
```